# existence of single surface patch that covers the trace of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to S$ be a unit-speed curve in a regular surface. If $\gamma$ is one-to-one, prove that there exists a single surface patch that covers the trace of $\gamma$.

Want to prove the above statement, but I don't know what injectivity of $\gamma$ shows. Could you give any hint? (This is an exercise of geodesics)